# Does strip_tags() handle embedded tags

Tags: php, xss, sanitization, strip-tags

I'm away from a computer with PHP installed and was wondering what the result of strip_tags() would be on the following text:
"<scr<h1>ipt>alert('oh oh')</scr</h1>ipt>"

Would it return:
"<script>alert('oh oh')</script>" (i.e. not recognize that by removing the obvious tag it exposed a new one)
or
"alert('oh oh')

I know that if it returns the first case I can just repeatedly call the function until I get out what I put in, but I'm curious.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suppose a valid question would be: Why do you want to do this? If you are looking to avoid XSS contextual encoding is the correct method, not stripping tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great question.

Nope, it doesn't strip anything from that string:

```
<?php
$b = "ipt>alert('oh oh')ipt>";
echo strip_tags($b);
?>
```

And the output is your original string: `ipt>alert('oh oh')ipt>`

**Edit**

In your second case it will print `alert('oh oh')` so it strips **all** that is looking like a tag in a single step

Comment: Sorry the post had edited my original string because I did not use the HTML character codes, could you take a look at it again for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It returns just:

```
alert('oh oh')
```